# ImportError: No module named 'pandas' Using Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
$ pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from pandas)
```

I am getting Import error while my system has already satisfied all requirements.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the import error?

Comment: How are you running your script? Are you sure, you're running the right python? What `which python` gives you?

Comment: in which version you are running pandas. check the python paths added to system environment

Comment: @Einstein sure ...

Comment: @Einstein Here it is.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: @AshishOdich what version are you getting when typing python in terminal?

Comment: @Exprator i have installed python2.7 system built in and Python3.5.2 i installed and python3.5.2 is default

Comment: means you are seeing something like this? 
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
in the terminal?

Comment: @Exprator Python3.5.0 is not, I have Python3.5.2 version

Comment: follow my ans, then tell if the error stays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be sure you are not having multiple Python versions that are confusing, you should run these commands

```
python -m pip install pandas
python -c 'import pandas'
```

It installs `pandas` and imports it with the same python version.

Of course, you have to update the `python` program in the above commands, in case it is not directly `python`.

If you have a `python3` executable, you can try

```
python3 -m pip install pandas
python3 -c 'import pandas'
```

You can even use absolute path, that would be returned by `which python`, `which python2` or `which python3`, ...

Comment: i have installed python2.7 system built in and Python3.5.2 i installed and python3.5.2 is default

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have multiple python3's. If everything else suggested doesn't work for you, a easy/hacky way is to do this before you import pandas, it will guarantee the usage of the correct interpreter. Do this just once, after its successfully installed, you no longer need to do that:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','pandas'])
import pandas
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives following Errors
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
 prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 732, in install
    **kwargs

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 835, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 322, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py'

Comment: You're not using the correct interpreter, this is the built-in python 3.5 not the one you downloaded. As you can see, it's in the /usr/local/ directory, which is where the built-in ones are stored. The one you downloaded should be in the framework directory

Comment: okay as you said that i am not using correct interpreter so please guide me which is the correct interpreter and how to solve this problem.